# In Rstudio I can't library any package now, the error message as below. But i can library R Gui

Tags: r, rstudio

In Rstudio I can't library any package now, the error message as below. But i can library R Gui.
Anyone can help ? Thanks!

```
> library(ggplot2)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 载入了名字空间‘rlang’ 0.4.11，但需要的是>= 1.0.0


> library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 载入了名字空间‘rlang’ 0.4.11，但需要的是>= 1.0.1
In addition: Warning message:
程辑包‘tidyverse’是用R版本4.1.3 来建造的
```

In Rstudio:

```
 > .libPaths()
    [1] "C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/R/win-library/4.1"
    [2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.0/library"
```

In Rgui:

```
  > .libPaths()
    [1] "C:/Users/andrewyang/Documents/R/win-library/4.1"
    [2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.0/library"
```

Comment: Run `.libPaths()` in RStudio and show us the result. Do the same in the R Gui. Since the errors seem to be `rlang` related, maybe try re-installing rlang in RStudio, `install.packages("rlang")`.

Comment: The resuls of  .libPaths() not the same , i have edited my post . And install.packages("rlang") always unsuceffully. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the error message from `install.packages("rlang")`?

Comment: Does R or Rstudio have permission to write in Users/Administrators? Was R installed by an administrator into a folder which other profiles cannot access?

Comment: I reinstalled R and Rstudio in same windows  administrator . It's ok now . Thanks for everyone!